# Remove WCF SOAP client request from memory

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have set up a little demo project to show my issue. I have a vanilla WCF service, communication is using SOAP over a basic http binding.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunService();
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void RunService()
    {
        new WebService().Create("http://localhost:50562/Service1.svc", "", "");
    }
}

class WebService
{
    public void Create(string url, string username, string password)
    {
        var binding = createBinding();
        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(url));
        var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, endpoint);
        var service = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

        Console.WriteLine(service.GetData(5));

        var channel = service as IClientChannel;
        channel.Close();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the HttpBinding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The binding.</returns>
    private BasicHttpBinding createBinding()
    {
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        return binding;
    }}
```

I have a console application that uses the ChannelFactory to create a proxy.  We make a call to the service close the connection then run GC.

The problem is that if you do a memory dump of the application at the Console.ReadKey() line at this point you can see the full SOAP request string in memory.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><GetData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><value>5</value></GetData></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

[image]

**The question is what is keeping this in memory and how do you remove it?** It's ok in this demo project but we would like to remove sensitive information (user credentials in the header) from memory in our real application.

So far I have looked at verifying we are closing the channel correctly and WCF MessageBuffers to see if these were keeping it in memory.  I have also used memory profilers to try and see what this object is but with no luck.  The only conclusion I have come to is it seems to be something under the hood of WCF as none of our, objects are alive at this point.

Any ideas?

Comment: were you able to figure this out, looks like that soap request is there to stay in memory as long as application is running

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that if you do a memory dump of the application at the Console.ReadKey() line at this point you can see the full SOAP request string in memory.

Try one of the following to potentially eliminate problems where message contents is visible insecurely:

1. **message-level** rather than transport-level encryption.  That way the message should not be decipherable from memory
2. **custom headers** and authentication providers: by using `SecureString` and custom header construction you will have complete control over header formation and encryption.  You can use this together with transport or further message-level encryption

The free set of steak knives here is that you enhance the message's security over the **wire** not just protect yourself from **memory dumps**.

### SecureString

OP's code:

```
public void Create(string url, string username, string password)
```

Why don't you use `SecureString` as a parameter?

MSDN has this to say about [`SecureString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx):

> SecureString is a string type that provides a measure of security. It tries to **avoid** storing potentially **sensitive** strings in process memory **as plain text**.  [More...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx)

e.g.

```
public void Create(string url, string username, SecureString password) { ... }
```

I would be more worried that your credentials are being **sent** over the wire **unencrypted** so be sure to use *message-level* or *transport-level* encryption too.

Comment: They are not being sent over the wire unencrypted as we use transport level encryption.  As stated this is a demo project to illustrate the issue.  Using secure string won't work as it is the SOAP request that is in memory - i.e. this is WCF creating the SOAP request in memory not me so it's not the password string in the method that is in memory.

Comment: @AshleyKelham Then switch to **message-level** encryption as I stated. Then it won't be visible as plain text.  Also, your code shows no evidence of transport-level encryption.

Comment: @AshleyKelham See revised answer

Comment: Why should the demo project show signs of any encryption.  The original question relates to what in WCF is keeping the SOAP request it makes in memory.  SecureString only keeps it secure whilst it holds the datra - the OP is about when WCF sends the SOAP request at which point it does not help as this is obviously not a SecureString.  Message level security is only applicable if we control the service.

Comment: @AshleyKelham You make zero sense and contradict yourself. I give up